# Why input keyboard not working in some iphone?

Tags: vue.js

I have a dedicated input component. It works correctly in all devices and browsers. But some users who have iPhone mobile phones, when they click on the input and the keyboard opens, they press any key, but nothing is typed.
What could be the problem?

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <input
      :id="uuid"
      :name="inputName"
      :type="inputType"
      :placeholder="placeHolder"
      @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
      required
      class="appearance-none block w-full  px-3 h-16 bg-[#f8f6f6] border-0 rounded-full text-lg font-yekanBakh focus:outline-none focus:ring-[#ffc8c3] focus:border-[#ffc8c3] sm:text-sm"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UniqueID from '@/features/UniqueID'
export default {
  props: {
    // inputId: {
    //   type: String,
    //   required: true,
    // },
    inputName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    inputType: {
      type: String,
      default: 'test',
    },
    placeHolder: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      uuid: UniqueID().getID()
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

Comment: Are things like `focus:ring-[#ffc8c3]` a valid class name? I would check for validity of HTML etc. first. I always debugged those kinds of issues with remote debugging of the phone's browser and look for error messages in the browser console.

Comment: This problem occurs in some iPhones. I've never seen . Only some of our customers reported this problem. @PeterKrebs

Comment: If it is specific to an iOS / Safari versions (or other browser) you will have to use remote-debugging on such a device or try emulating. Otherwise I would clean up the code so it only consists of standard HTML/CSS/JS so that those issues are less likely.